# Importing data without exact reference

Tags: open-policy-agent

I have a policy that has the following imports

```
package abc.xyz

import data.abc_xyz_sourceOne as sourceOne
import data.abc_xyz_sourceTwo as sourceTwo

…
```

If I were to include another import it would look like this

```
import data.abc_xyz_sourceThree as sourceThree
```

If I do I include that import, but haven’t deployed the bundle that contains sourceThree then OPA will not be able to activate the policy referencing the above data because of the failed import.

My question is, can I define an import that uses something like * so that it looks like:

```
import data.abc_xyz* as source
```

The prefix will always be `abc_xyz`. If I could do something like the import above I would just have to deploy the bundle that contains `sourceThree` and not also include the a new import statement in my policy exactly referencing `sourceThree`. Hence avoiding the issue where OPA can’t activate the bundle because of an import it can’t resolve.

If not, is there another way to overcome having to always define exact import references?

Comment: Hey, once `data.abc_xyz_sourceThree` is loaded (from another bundle) then it'll be defined in `package abc.xyz`. Until then, anything that depends on `sourceThree` will just be undefined, other parts of the policy not depending on it will 'still work'.